# Prove: $gcd(am,an)=|a|gcd(m,n)$

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

> Prove: $$gcd(am,an)=|a|gcd(m,n)$$
>   For all $a,m,n\in \mathbb{Z}$

I am trying to utilize the fact that if $a\mid b$ and $b \mid a$ then $a=\pm b$

$gcd(am,an)=amu+anv=a(mu+nv)$ for $u,v\in \mathbb{Z}$

Now $a\cdot gcd(m,n)\mid a(mu+nv)=gcd(am,an)$

On the other hand

$a\cdot gcd(m,n)=a(mk+nl)=amk+anl$ for $k,l\in \mathbb{Z}$

now $gcd(am,an)\mid amk+anl=a\cdot gcd(m,n)$

So we got $gcd(am,an)\mid a\cdot gcd(m,n)$ and $a\cdot gcd(m,n)\mid gcd(am,mn)$ and therefore $gcd(am,an)=\pm a\cdot gcd(m,n)$ or $gcd(am,an)=|a|\cdot gcd(m,n)$

Is the proof valid?

Comment: It's almost fine. I would just add that $\gcd(m,n)=mk+nl$ for some $k,l\in\mathbf Z$ just after ‘On the other hand’, to have no ambiguity as to which Bézout's identity is used for which g.c.d.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

The ideal $(am,an)$ is equal to $a(m,n)$, and the g.c.d. is the positive generator of this ideal.

Comment: I am editing the qeustion

Comment: @gbox: You want to do it directly in terms of divisibility?

Comment: I realized that it is written that $a,m,n\in \mathbb{Z}$ so in the "worst case" $gcd(m,n)=1$ So I assume that there is one, so I completed the proof (not sure that it is valid)